Css + iPhone overflow content of the child div is not showing outside of the parent if parent has overflow:auto property
In iPhone overflow content of the child div is not showing outside of the parent div if given property overflow:auto to parent for scrolling content.
The close Icon does not show the iPhone device, If the change overflow:auto to visible scroll is gone but the icon showing on the front end, I think overflow:auto is creating an issue in iPhone devices. HTML + CSS Code sample has been added.
Screenshots have been added for reference.


<div class="sections nav-sections">
    <div class="section-items nav-sections-items mage-tabs-disabled" role="tablist">
        <div class="section-item-content nav-sections-item-content" id="store.menu" data-role="content" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
            <nav class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
                <ul id="ui-id-1" role="menu" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content">
                    <li class="desktop-hidden mobile-close-container ui-menu-divider ui-widget-content">
                        <button class="mobile-close"></button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="level0 nav-1 category-item first level-top parent ui-menu-item">
                        <a href="javascript:void();" class="level-top ui-menu-item-wrapper" aria-haspopup="true" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-caret-1-e"></span><span>Shop</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="level0 nav-2 category-item level-top parent ui-menu-item">
                        <a href="javascript:void();" class="level-top ui-menu-item-wrapper" aria-haspopup="true" id="ui-id-214" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
                            <span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-caret-1-e"></span><span>Pharmacy</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="level0 parent ambrands-menu-item ui-menu-item" data-ambrands-js="brands-menu-link">
                        <a href="#/brands/" class="level-top ambrands-link ui-menu-item-wrapper" id="ui-id-285" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
                            <span class="ambrands-label ambrands-menu-label">Brands</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="level0 nav-3 level-top ui-menu-item">
                        <a href="#/value-picks" class="level-top ui-menu-item-wrapper" id="ui-id-287" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span>Value Picks</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="level0 nav-4 level-top ui-menu-item">
                        <a href="#/deals" class="level-top ui-menu-item-wrapper" id="ui-id-288" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span>Deals</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="level0 nav-5 level-top ui-menu-item">
                        <a href="#/faq" class="level-top ui-menu-item-wrapper" id="ui-id-289" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span>FAQ</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="level0 nav-6 last level-top parent ui-menu-item">
                        <a href="javascript:void();" class="level-top ui-menu-item-wrapper" aria-haspopup="true" id="ui-id-290" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
                            <span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-caret-1-e"></span><span>Free Shipping On Orders $49+</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.nav-sections {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: left 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: left 0.3s;
    transition: left 0.3s;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 54px);
    background: #F9F7F7;
}


Did you try overflow: scroll, as that seems to be what you're after?

yes it's the same result as overflow: auto
